# Object not a reference - Quickblox chat in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, quickblox

I am having trouble getting quickblox chat working on phonegap (javascript).I have used the revealing module pattern to expose instead of 'require' and this is the broken piece of code:

```
var chatParams = {
            onConnectFailed: onConnectFailed,
            onConnectSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
            onConnectClosed: onConnectClosed,
            onChatMessage: onChatMessage
        };

        QB.createSession(params, function(err, result) {
            if (err==null) {
                chatUser = {
                    id: result.user_id,
                    pass: params.password
                };
                connectChat(chatParams);
            }
            else {
                alert("Something went wrong, please try again later or contact us at contact@domain.co.uk if the problem persists.");
            }
        });

        function connectChat(chatParams) {
            //This line here:
            var chatService = new QBChat(chatParams);
            console.log(chatService);
            // connect to QB chat service
            chatService.connect(chatUser);
        };
```

I am getting the error 'object not a reference' at the highlighted line.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code as an example to join chat:

```
 QB.chat.connect({userId: user.id, password: user.pass}, function(err, roster) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(roster);
    }
  });
```

instead of

```
  function connectChat(chatParams) {
        //This line here:
        var chatService = new QBChat(chatParams);
        console.log(chatService);
        // connect to QB chat service
        chatService.connect(chatUser);
    };
```